# Buttons have their own coordinate system according to the "grid_location" method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid

I'm trying to use the `grid_location` method, from the *Grid Geometry Manager*, in Tkinter, but it seems that I'm doing something wrong.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import * 


root = Tk()

b=Button(root, text="00")
b.grid(row=0, column=0)
b2=Button(root, text="11")
b2.grid(row=1, column=1)
b3=Button(root, text="22")
b3.grid(row=2, column=2)
b4=Button(root, text="33")
b4.grid(row=3, column=3)
b5=Button(root, text="44")
b5.grid(row=4, column=4)

def mouse(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)
    print(root.grid_location(event.x, event.y))

root.bind("<Button-1>", mouse)

root.mainloop()
```

When I click outside the Buttons, it works, but when I click inside of any Button, it seems that each button has its own coordinate system. So, each button is on the (0, 0) cell, despite that in the code, they are on a regular grid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that each button "has it's own coordinate system". More accurately, though, the `event.x` and `event.y` values are relative to the widget associated with the event rather than the widget's parent or the root window.

If you really do need the row and column that the widget is in you can use `grid_info` to get the row and column of the widget associated with the event. For example:

```
def mouse(event):
    grid_info = event.widget.grid_info()
    print("row:", grid_info["row"], "column:", grid_info["column"])
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, worked perfectly. I tried get_info before but didn't know how to use it. Good explanation too.